# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed, mysql

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

Whenever I try and run this code I get: "java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed".  It works without closing the connection but i'm curious as to why I get this error and what would be the correct way to close the connection, Here is the code:

```
    public ResultSet UpdateTable(){

            Connection con = connect();
            ResultSet resultset;
            Statement s = null;
            resultset = null;
        try{
            s = con.createStatement();
            resultset =  s.executeQuery("select * from customera");
            return resultset;

            }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            //con.close();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                s.close();
                resultset.close();
                con.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, the first thing I'd do is print the stack trace so you know for sure which line that's coming from.

Comment: How do I print the stacktrace, I tried System.out.println(e.printstacktrace()) but doesnt work - I get "void type not allowed here".

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();` will print it by itself, without using `println()`.

Comment: I tried that aswell but nothing is printed just get a long error message in red writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would rather check whether they have any reference or not, then close them.

```
 finally {

        if (resultset != null) {
            resultset.close();
        }

        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }

        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }

    }
```

I suspect, issue with

```
return resultset;
```

Since, you are closing the `Connection` and `Statement` before returning the `ResultSet`, so `ResultSet` might not be available. You must be aware `finally` block will execute before returning the value. That is also why, your code is working when you left your `Connection` open.

So, instead you should store the result into some data structure and return.

Comment: @JohnCollins Did you removed `resultset.close();` ?

Comment: @Ravi this isn't a NullPointerException.  They aren't going to be null even if they are closed.  Although maybe you could have similar code that DOES check if they are closed.

Comment: @DM I know that, they aren't NPE, but I was suggesting correct way of closing them.

Comment: @Ravi Well, OK, but then you aren't really answering the question (even if it's a good suggestion.)

Comment: @JohnCollins please check my post now

Comment: @DM I just answered the question as well.

Comment: Thanks, so would I store the resultset into an arraylist and then return the arraylist?

Comment: The problem is i'm using DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(mySql.UpdateTable()) which requires a resultset not an arraylist

Comment: @JohnCollins So, why don't you call that method there itself ? Inside method ? And, if you can't then, whether you have written that method ? If yes, then you consider changing this method to accept List. That is n't look good design to me

Comment: @JohnCollins If it requires a `ResultSet`, return the `ResultSet`.  But then you can't close it until you're done with it.

Comment: @Ravi I'm using netbeans and have an event for a button and the code in that event is  jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(mySql.UpdateTable()) I did not write this, that is an add on for java which puts the result set into the table.  I then have another class with the MySQL queries in including the UpdatetTable method.

Comment: @DM so when would I close the connection ?

Comment: @JohnCollins use `jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultset)` instead of returning the value

Comment: The problem is jTable1 (auto generated code with netbeans) is in one class and made a seperate class for the MySQL stuff, should I put the mysql stuff in the class where jTable1 is ?

Comment: @JohnCollins Yes.

Comment: I'd say "maybe".  It depends on how your code is structured.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is likely not coming from the code you show.  Instead, it is being generated by other code, as a result of you closing your `ResultSet` and `Statement` before that other code uses it.  (Closing the `Statement` also closes its `ResultSet`, according to the documentation.)

You can either call whatever code you need to finish using the `ResultSet` in this method, or you can just return the `ResultSet` and have it be the calling code's responsibility to close it.  What you decide may depend on your other code, but I'd prefer making it be the calling code's responsibility (since it's specifically getting a `ResultSet` from this method, it should know it has to close it.)

As a side note, you should better differentiate your exception messages, so you can tell where they are coming from.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense but how would the caller close it if its being called from another class.

Comment: Well, how is this method called?  I assume you have something like `ResultSet r = UpdateTable();` or something similar?  Then you just have to do `r.close()` after you've done everything you need to do with `r`.

Comment: But how about closing the connection ? and the statment

Comment: The `ResultSet` has a `getStatement()` method, and the `Statement` has a `getConnection()` method, so you can get these from the `ResultSet` and close them.